# IF ELSE in Razor for two different columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

So I have two columns in my table. Is Locked and Changes Pending. When the Is Locked active then the edit is disabled. But on the others so Unlocked, and Changes Pending you can access edit in the Action Menu.

So far I have the Locked working, but on the others, the Edit is still disabled.

```
<td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm text-center">
                @if (t.IsLocked)
                 {
                //<span class="fa fa-lock fa-lg writer-locked" data-toggle="tooltip" title="This song is locked, pending changes."></span>
                 }
                 else
                 {
                //<span class="fa fa-lock fa-lg writer-locked" data-toggle="tooltip" title="This song is locked, pending changes."></span>
                <span class="fa fa-unlock fa-lg writer-unlocked" data-toggle="tooltip" title="This song is unlocked, there are no pending changes." aria-hidden="true"></span>
                 }
            </td>
            <td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm text-center">
                @if (t.HasActiveAmendment)
                 {
                //<span class="fa fa-pencil-square-o writers-cross text-center" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="tooltip" title="This song has been edited, pending changes."></span>
                 }
                else
                {
            //<span class="fa fa-pencil-square-o writers-cross text-center" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="tooltip" title="This song has been edited, pending changes."></span>
            <span class="fa fa-minus writers-check text-center" data-toggle="tooltip" title="This song has no pending changes." aria-hidden="true"></span>
                }
            </td>
            <td class="updateTableRow text-center">
                <div class="dropdownContainer btn-group text-right">
                    <button id="@actionWriterId" type="button" class="btn btn-primary br2 btn-xs fs12 dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        Action
                        <span class="caret ml5"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
                        <li>
                            @if (t.IsLocked)
                            {
                            <a href="#" id="@editWriterId" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit" data-rowhover="editTableRow" class="js_EditWriter">Edit</a>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                            <a class="isDisabled" data-toggle="tooltip" title="You cannot edit this song until pending writer edits are approved">Edit</a>
                            }
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" id="@deleteWriterId" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete" data-rowhover="deleteTableRow" class="js_DeleteWriter">Delete</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
            tableRowIndex++;
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're saying that you want the edit to be disabled only when IsLocked - it looks like you just have your if statement round the wrong way, so I would try changing

```
@if (t.IsLocked) 
{
    <a href="#" id="@editWriterId" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit" data-rowhover="editTableRow" class="js_EditWriter">Edit</a>
}
else
{
    <a class="isDisabled" data-toggle="tooltip" title="You cannot edit this song until pending writer edits are approved">Edit</a>
}
```

To

```
@if (t.IsLocked)                 
{
    <a class="isDisabled" data-toggle="tooltip" title="You cannot edit this song until pending writer edits are approved">Edit</a>
}
else
{                     
    <a href="#" id="@editWriterId" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit" data-rowhover="editTableRow" class="js_EditWriter">Edit</a>
 }
```

Eg.

- If locked, cannot edit as disabled;
- Else, can edit